# Laravel: All pages but index are NOT FOUND

Tags: laravel, amazon-ami, ec2-ami

I have just deployed my app to an AMI ec2 server and following some tutorials, got to one that explains to modify config/app.php like:

```
/*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application URL
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This URL is used by the console to properly generate URLs when using
    | the Artisan command line tool. You should set this to the root of
    | your application so that it is used when running Artisan tasks.
    |
    */

    'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://52.67.251.19/'),
```

... and change httpd.conf as follows:

```
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
# 
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/nnid/public/"

# 
# Relax access to content within /var/www.
#
<Directory "/var/www/nnid/public/">
    AllowOverride None
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

But all pages, besides the landing page, are NOT FOUND. Any hints?

Comment: DocumentRoot has an extra "html" folder.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have mod_rewrite turned on on your server.

Also Laravel 5.6 ships with this .htaccess file inside of the public folder.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Just make sure it matches your current one.

Comment: I certainly am! Quer dizer, eu sou sim :p

Comment: Cara, tudo bem?
Então, não estou conseguindo acertar isso de jeito nenhum.

Comment: Você tem esse código dentro da pasta public? Esse código é o que diz o Apache como processar os pedidos.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!
The problem was at the httpd.conf at mode ReWrite. Changed to All and works like a breeze!